# Narrowing down a C++ concept to exclude certain types

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts

Suppose I would want to overload the left shift operator for `ostream`s and all containers.

This is what I'm currently have (compile with `-fconcepts`):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Container>
concept bool Iterable = requires(Container t) {
        { *t.begin()++, t.end() };
};

template<Iterable T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& t) {
    for(const auto& it: t) {
        out << it << " " ;
    }
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    std::string str = "something";
    // std::cout << str << std::endl; // compile error if the template is defined
    return 0;
}
```

The problem however, is that this there is already a version of the `ostream&<<` for `std::string`.

Is there a general (something like a `requires not` expression) or specific (maybe similar to partial specialization by which I can exclude concrete classes) way to exclude something in a concept?

If not, what is the correct way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<Iterable T>
    requires !requires(std::ostream o, T a) { operator<<(o, a); }
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& t) {
    for(const auto& it: t) {
        out << it << " " ;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Add a requirement that the type does not already have an `operator<<` defined. I am not 100% sure this should work, but it does work on [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/9j2vAH).

(simply `o << a` crashes gcc)

Comment: This recursively defines the type `T` has a `<<` defined only if it doesn't have `<<` defined.  That seems dangerous, because once the `<<` definition has been added, the type *no longer qualifies* as having a `<<` defined.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont that's my worrying exactly. Not sure how the standard/proposal deals with this.