# Exclude several types from an overload of operator<<

Tags: c++, c++17, operator-overloading, ambiguous

This is a follow-up of [C++ generic overload of operator<< for STL containers produces ambiguous overload error with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77320573/c-generic-overload-of-operator-for-stl-containers-produces-ambiguous-overloa)
The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321100/2707864) works very well.
But upon further testing, I found at least one class that already had its `operator<<` and also matched my overload, `setfill`.

My MCVE is posted below.
Line #1 (see comment) produces compilation error `ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>'} and 'std::_Setfill<char>')`.

Is there any way to add multiple classes for excluding in `std::enable_if_t<not (std::is_same_v<std::string, Container<T...>>), ...` ?
What is the specific syntax for my case, and a generic syntax to keep adding exclusions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct contains : std::bool_constant<(std::is_same<T, Ts>{} || ...)>
{};
template <template <class... K> class Container, class ...T>
std::enable_if_t<not (std::is_same_v<std::string, Container<T...>>),
std::ostream&> operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Container<T...>& c)
{
    os << "[";

    size_t nvals = 0;
    for ( auto iter = c.begin() ; iter != c.end() ; iter++ ) {
        os << *iter;
        nvals++;
        if (iter != --(c.end()))
            os << ", ";
        if (nvals > MAX_PRINT_VALS) {
           os << "... (total of " << c.size() << " values)";
           break;
        }
    }

    os << "]";
    return os;
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    //============================================================
    // Print iomanip flags
    ostringstream msg;
    int dT = 65205;
    msg << std::setfill('0')              // <--- Error Line #1
        << std::setw(2)
        << dT / 86400
        << "d";
    cout << "Elapsed time = " << msg << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Realted**

1. [Narrowing down a C++ concept to exclude certain types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912163/narrowing-down-a-c-concept-to-exclude-certain-types)

Comment: How do you define "container"? You make no attempt to verify that the template parameter `Container` in fact designates some type that meets your definition of a "container", whatever it might be.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - You are right. I would gladly receive suggestions on how to do that.
It will likely get rid of many other cases in the future with `ambiguous overload`.
I am not sure this restriction would also get rid of the current error (hopefully it will).

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://godbolt.org/z/d1KbqEjKf), perhaps. This is a pretty naive definition of a "container" (something that has member functions `begin()`, `end()` and `size()`). Adjust to taste.

Comment: ... and if you want to exclude _all_ containers that already have an `operator<<(std::ostream&, ...` overload (not only `std::string`, but `std::string_view`s etc) then you could add [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7T6Ebq1aK) to Igor's example.